SSMS erroneously opens files that were previously open before system
I have SSMS open all the time and work with many .sql files. Whenever I need to restart my computer, I manually close all files, which can sometime be 10+ at a given time. I save what I need and close out.
After restarting my computer, when I open SSMS back up, it starts opening all the files that I had previously closed, sometimes going even further back to files that I had closed quite some time ago.
I would understand this behavior if I had let the system restart close out everything, but this is not the case. I'm not trying to recover anything. I want to open SSMS as a blank slate.
Is there a setting somewhere that needs to be adjusted for fix this? I can't find anything. Thanks.
